# How do i create "Link a Document" in document Library from SharePoint Designer workflow 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

[image]

I want to create document shortcut link from SharePoint Designer workflow 2013. but i am not able to find proper solution.

I have tried using below action but it is creating document itself. not creating link. can you help me for that?

**Create item in this list (Output to Variable: create)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct way, since its not available as content type. Below is the way to achieve this, please see if this suits your requirement

1. Go to library setting and allow content types
2. Add "Link to document" content type
3. Reopen Sharepoint desinger workflow
4. Use same action "Create item"
5. Select your document library
6. Click on add field and choose content type
7. In the dropdown, you should see "Link to document" option
8. Set necessary link name and path.

Tried with designer 2013 workflow and seems to work.

**NOTE**: Disable "Link" from NEW button from toolbar of the library, else it will be duplicated.  (Since we enabled link to document content type )

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and it is working now. but i am facing one issue. when i click on shortcut, file is downloaded instead of open in new tab. can you help me with that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great..can you please mark this as answered? for download issue, you might wan to raise another question. but it fairly depends on the type of file, only certain file type opens in browser and do check under advanced setting for default behavior